# Is there a way to target the arrow from an OP bow via command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make an effect trail for a specific weapon in MC, a bow with power 120.  I want to use a command block to target any arrow with the damage it should be doing (63) and summon a trail of splash potions.

I also want to kill any arrow entities that have `inGround=True`

Is there any way to do this or do I have to come up with something else?

Attempt:

```
/execute @e[type=Arrow,damage=63,inGround=0] ~ ~ ~ summon ThrownPotion ~ ~ ~ {Potion:{id:potion,Damage:8197}}
/kill @e[type=Arrow,inGround=True]
```

Each unfortunately just affects all arrows.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5):

Target selectors do not support direct NBT data input. You must assign a label to the target using `/scoreboard` first, and then target the entity based on its label.

**Prerequisites:**

Objective to hold the value.

```
/scoreboard objectives add SpecialArrow dummy
```

**Clock commands:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Assign a score based on the arrow's NBT data. Note that you must properly declare tag-types; in this case, "damage" has a tag-type of `double`, so you must include a decimal, while "inGround" has a tag-type of `byte`, so its value is appended with a "b". The command assigns a score of 1 if the arrow has a particular damage as well as not being in the ground.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow] SpecialArrow 1 {damage:63.0,inGround:0b}
   ```
2. Perform the commands you'd like, targeting arrows with a `SpecialArrow` score of exactly 1.

   ```
   /execute @e[type=Arrow,score_SpecialArrow_min=1,score_SpecialArrow=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ThrownPotion ~ ~ ~ {Potion:{id:potion,Damage:8197}}
   ```
3. Afterwards, the score is set to 2 if that particular arrow is now in the ground.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow] SpecialArrow 2 {damage:63.0,inGround:1b}
   ```
4. And finally, the /kill command, targeting based on score.

   ```
   /kill @e[type=Arrow,score_SpecialArrow_min=2]
   ```